# Update com select CTE Erro

Tags: sql, query, sql-update, sql-server-2012

Estou tendo dificuldades de realizar um update com select CTE. Quero atualizar o campo taridinclusao. Abaixo é a consulta e logo abaixo é o update que tentei realizar, porém, ocorre o seguinte o erro: "A tabela derivada 'historico' não é atualizável porque uma coluna da tabela derivada é derivada ou constante"

-> QUERY

```
WITH historico AS (
  SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao
    FROM tarefa t
   WHERE t.tarid = 167920 and t.taridinclusao IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao
    FROM historico h
         INNER JOIN tarefa t ON t.tarid = h.tarefa_inclusao
   WHERE h.tarefa_inclusao IS NOT NULL and t.taridinclusao IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT top(1)h.*
  FROM historico h
 ORDER BY h.tarefa_inclusao asc
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

-> UPDATE

```
WITH historico
AS
(SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao
    FROM tarefa t
   WHERE t.tarid = 167920 and t.taridinclusao IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao
    FROM historico h
         INNER JOIN tarefa t ON t.tarid = h.tarefa_inclusao
   WHERE h.tarefa_inclusao IS NOT NULL and t.taridinclusao IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE historico
SET tarefa_inclusao = tarefa_inclusao
SELECT top(1)h.*
  FROM historico h
 ORDER BY h.tarefa_inclusao asc
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Alguém poderia ?

Comment: Qual o objetivo dessa `query`? Da forma que você colocou você está dando `update` em uma tabela que é apenas resultado de uma `CTE` e existe só neste escopo, fora que você está atualizando uma coluna com ela mesmo...

Comment: `Update` não tem `select` em sua estrutura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não atualize o campo na `CTE` e sim na sua tabela `tarefa` da seguinte forma:

```
WITH historico AS (
  SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao,
         t.tarid AS tarefa_referencia,
         1 AS nivel
    FROM tarefa t
   WHERE t.tarid = 167920
     AND t.taridinclusao IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao,
         h.tarefa_referencia,
         h.nivel + 1
    FROM historico h
         INNER JOIN tarefa t ON t.tarid = h.tarefa_inclusao
   WHERE h.tarefa_inclusao IS NOT NULL
     AND t.taridinclusao IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE t
   SET t.taridinclusao = h.tarefa_inclusao
  FROM tarefa t
       INNER JOIN historico h ON h.tarefa_referencia = t.tarid
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM historico h2
                   WHERE h2.nivel > h.nivel)
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Nesta `query` estou atualizando a tabela `tarefa` com base nos históricos gerados pegando apenas o nível mais alto da recursão.

Comment: Tudo certo meu jovem. Obg